# How to shift the values of a certain group by different amounts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    user   data
0   Kevin    1
1   Kevin    3
2   Sara     5
3   Kevin    23
...
```

And I want to get the historical values (looking let's say 2 entries forward) as rows:

```
    user   data data_1 data_2
0   Kevin    1    3      23
1   Sara     5   24      NaN
2   Kim      ...
...
```

Right now I'm able to do this through the following command:

```
_temp = df.groupby(['user'], as_index = False)['data']
for i in range(1,2):
   data['data_{0}'.format(i)] = _temp.shift(-1)
```

I feel like my approach is very inefficient and that there is a much faster way to do this (esp. when the number of lookahead/lookback values go up)!

Comment: I don't think this is ineficient. My 2 cents : You may want to ponder your problem, maybe you don't need to shift all the data, but a portion of it -- if you want to talk about performance, make some benchmark, and test up to which point this function is useful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `set_index()` and [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
m=df.assign(k=df.groupby('user').cumcount().astype(str)).set_index(['user','k']).unstack()
m.columns=m.columns.map('_'.join)
print(m)
```

---

```
       data_0  data_1  data_2
user                         
Kevin     1.0     3.0    23.0
Sara      5.0     NaN     NaN
```